# Star Trek TNG discrepancies with things leaving the holodeck

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was rewatching the first season when I realized that they weren’t following the “nothing created in the holodeck can leave the holodeck” rule consistently. In the pilot episode, Wesley falls in the water in the holodeck and is still soaking wet after he leaves, and in “The big goodby” Picard still has lipstick on his lips from when the female prospective  client kissed him in the holodeck earlier on. However at the end of the episode when Redbrick and Leech step out of it, they disintegrate after just a few moments. Was this just inconsistencies in the writing, or are there other rules about what can/cannot leave the holodeck that I’m not aware of?

Comment: The holodeck was sort of a combination transporter/replicator as well as just hologram projector. Things like food, water (i.e. snowballs in one episode and water from O'Brien's kayaking trip), and the lipstick were replicated rather than holoprojected.